# Use Auth0 API protected route with Express route handlers

Tags: node.js, express, auth0

I implemented protected API routes in Express using the [Auth0 quick start](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/nodejs#configure-auth0-apis). Protected routes are handled with a middleware function called `checkJwt`, [provided by Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/nodejs/01-authorization#configure-the-middleware). It runs whenever one of the GET methods is called. This process works well if I manage all my routes in `server.js`.

**How can I separate out the route handling and still preserve the protected API routes?**

`server.js` *working code with protected routes*.

```js
import colors from 'colors'
import cors from 'cors'
import express from 'express'
import morgan from 'morgan'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import connectDB from './db.js'
import checkJwt from './middleware/auth.middleware.js'
import { getStudents, getStudent } from './controllers/students.controller.js'

dotenv.config()
connectDB()
export const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }))
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  app.use(morgan('dev'))
}

//handle routing internally
app.get('/api/students/:id', checkJwt, getStudent)
app.get('/api/students', checkJwt, getStudents)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6000
app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(
    `Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold
  )
)
```

I want to divorce out the route handling as my code grows. I can't figure out where to put `checkJwt` once I separate out the routing.

`server.js` **desired code structure** is:

```js
import colors from 'colors'
import cors from 'cors'
import express from 'express'
import morgan from 'morgan'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import connectDB from './db.js'
import studentsRouter from './routes/students.routes.js'

dotenv.config()
connectDB()
const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }))
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  app.use(morgan('dev'))
}

// handle routing externally
const apiRouter = express.Router()
app.use('/api', apiRouter)
apiRouter.use('/students', studentsRouter)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6000
app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(
    `Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold
  )
)
```

Routes are implemented in the `students.routes.js` Route handler.

```js
import express from 'express'
import { getStudent, getStudents } from '../controllers/students.controller.js'

const router = express.Router()

// where can I implement checkJwt?
router.route('/').get(getStudents)
router.route('/:id').get(getStudent)

export default router
```

Is it possible to simplify the code by moving the routing, and still protect my routes?

Comment: you can use checkJwt in your students.routes.js : ```router.route('/').get([checkJwt] , getStudents)```

Comment: That seems to have worked. Thank you very much. If you post this as an answer I will mark it as the solution. If you can explain why it works, that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use any middleware like this in your router:

```
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/').get([checkJwt, secondMiddleware, ...] , getStudents);
```

based on documentation:
[express-routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

> You can provide multiple callback functions that behave like middleware to handle a request. The only exception is that these callbacks might invoke next('route') to bypass the remaining route callbacks. You can use this mechanism to impose pre-conditions on a route, then pass control to subsequent routes if there’s no reason to proceed with the current route.